# Outlook 2007 - Easiest and most inexpensive way to share a calendar between 5-10 people?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

What's the easiest way to share a calendar in outlook 2007 between 5-10 people on a local network?  I have tried sharepoint and the password prompts are too much of a pain.  Security is not an issue; ease and functionality are the priorities.

Comment: Are you using Outlook with Exchange? Have you tried just using a simple shared calendar in a public folder?

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication in SharePoint?

Comment: No exchange.  How do I create a simple shared calendar in a public folder?  We all have access via the local network to a shared file system.  Can I use that to "host" the calendar?

Comment: You can use Google calendar to do something like this...

Comment: "Are you using Windows authentication in SharePoint?"

I'm not sure.  How do I check?

Comment: I think he is referring to an Exchange Public folder.

Answer (score 1):

Popular online syncing solutions for an Outlook calendar are [Windows Live Calendar](http://windowslive.com/Online/Calendar) and [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar/). If an Internet connection is not an option, you can share a calendar via a local WebDAV server (see your Outlook help for detailed steps).