# How to access my wife's Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, network-shares, microsoft-outlook-2007

My wife and I both have Outlook 2007 and are networked in our SOHO. We nave no server.
Is there a way I can access her calendar from my desktop to make appointments for her, or to check her bookings?

Comment: Sync her Calendar to something like Google Calendar then sync her account with yourself

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i share my outlook 2007 calendar with outlook 2003](http://superuser.com/questions/193999/how-can-i-share-my-outlook-2007-calendar-with-outlook-2003), http://superuser.com/questions/86517/outlook-2007-easiest-and-most-inexpensive-way-to-share-a-calendar-between-5-10?rq=1

Comment: Google Calendars would be easy.  You use outlook to export everything to ICS and then you could import them in either 1 or 2 google accounts.  If you choose 2 accounts you click the drop down next to the calendar "Share" and enter your wife's email assign full access. Do the reverse on your her account. Done. I have 50+ google calendars in 1 account.  In google each calendar is separate so you can show/hide calendars with a single click. I am not as familiar with outlooks options.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link on [how to delegate access](https://experts.missouristate.edu/display/csvhelpdesk/Outlook+Calendar+Permissions).

In 2013, 2010 start with **File** then **info** then **delegate**. Then add.

In 2007 **Tools** → **Options** → **Delegates** → **Add*.

Enter the your email address in your wife account. Give yourself  **Editor** access.
If you like you can check the **Delegate receives copies of meeting-related messages sent to me** option.

From the Outlook 2007 section.

> 1. In Outlook 2007 click on the Calendar view.
> 2. In the left-hand pane, find the calendar that you want to share under "My Calendars." Right-click on it and a context menu will
>      appear. On that menu, click Properties.
> 3. The properties window will appear. Click the Permissions tab.
> 4. Click the Add button.
> 5. Search for the users you want to add in the Global Address List. For each user that you want to grant permissions to, highlight their
>      name and click Add.
> 6. Once all the users that you want to grant permissions to are in the list, click OK.
> 7. Back on the permissions tab, you can edit the permissions for each user you added by highlighting their name and selecting the
>      appropriate permission level from the drop-down menu. You can also
>      define custom permissions using the check-boxes below the drop-down
>      menu.
> 8. When you are done defining permissions for the other users, click OK.

Along the way you will have an opportunity to share tasks,inbox,contact,notes, and etc if you want to share these also select them when you see them.

Comment: @JohnBensin  There is your summary enjoy.

Comment: @ChrisF  There is your summary enjoy.